# association of RNA-seq data with particular genes

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a list of genes (as a bed file) and a genome-wide RNA-seq data set (also stored as a bed file). I'm currently trying to develop a python script that allows me to extract the read counts 500bp upstream to 2000bp downstream of the transcription start site, i.e. the beginning of a gene, and store these values in an array for future use.

Currently, my script looks like this:

```
feature_genes=np.zeros((6576, 2501))

for lines in feature:
   for i in range(0,6575):
        if line[5]==lines[5] and line[5]=='+' and line[0]==lines[0] and int(lines[1])>=int(line[1])- 500 and int(lines[1])<=int(line[1])+2000:
            feature_genes[i][int(lines[1])-int(line[1])+500]=lines[4] 
        elif line[5]=='-' and line[0]==lines[0] and int(lines[2])+500>=int(line[2]) and int(lines[2])-2000<=int(line[2]) and lines[5]=='-':
            feature_genes[i][-1*(int(lines[2])-int(line[2])-500)]=lines[4]
```

where feature represents my read in bedfile and genes my list of genes, each line of which contains the read counts at a particular nucleotide (this is strand-specific information and excludes any base pairs where no read was observed) or the position of a gene respectively.

NB. .bed files are formatted like this:

```
Position 

0 chromosome
1 transcription start site
2 transcription termination site
3 feature name
4 read count
5 strand
```

Can anyone think of a way to this efficiently? My code takes forever to run (python newbie).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to not use python, but bedtools. There are a few ways to do this, here is one:

1) extend your TSS upstream by x nucleotides and it downstream by x nucleotides, so that math is already taken care of.

2) use intersectBed with the abam option to output RNA-Seq reads covering the region of interest (or if you just want the depth of coverage, coverageBed)